# How do i get the values of object in arrays react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, list, object

Object { rows: (1) […], count: 3 }
​
My api is giving me this

count: 3
​rows: Array [ {…} ]
​​0: Object { ELIGIBILITATE: "2022-04-10", BFA: "2022-04-11", id: "c53d945e-4bb1-49ab-91ca-c9e046ac5de7", … }
​​​Name:"Paul"
​​​BFA: "2022-04-11"

how to display the values in react? i've tried the following with no luck

```
   class Test extends React.Component{
constructor()
{
    super()
    this.state={
        row:[            
        ]
    }
}

componentDidMount()
{
    const axios = require('axios');

    // Make a request for a user with a given ID
    axios.get('myapi')
      .then( response =>{
        // handle success
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({row:response.data});
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
      console.log(error);
      })
      .then(function () {
        // always executed
      
      });
    
}

render() {

    const { row } = this.state;


    return (

      <div>

        <div>

          {Object.keys(row).map(([key, value]) => {
 console.log(row);
            return (

              <div>

                {key} = {value.Nume}

              </div>

            );

          })}

        </div>

      </div>

    );

}
```

}
export default Test

Comment: `this.setState({ row: response.data.rows });`?

Comment: In Postman i get this{
    "rows": [
        {
            "ELIGIBILITATE": "2022-04-10",
            "BFA": "2022-04-11",
            "id": "c53d945e-4bb1-49ab-91ca-c9e046ac5de7",
            "Nume": "Paul", still, no luck on displaying the values @Chris G

Comment: The API returns an Object with a `rows` key. To get the array you thus need `response.data.rows`. I would do `const { rows } = response.data;` then `this.setState({ rows });` (it's an array of rows, so the state array should be called row**s**. Next you render it: `{this.state.rows.map(row => <p key={row.id}>{row.BFA}</p>)}` should work for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:**

That's because the value you're setting for `state.row` is an array.

Try this: `this.setState({row:response.data.rows[0]});`

**Explanation**

The response from your request - `response.data` - is an object with the following keys: `count` and `rows`.

`count` is self explanatory.

`rows` on the otherhand is returned as an array of objects, which is what you're setting the value of `state.row` to.

Since you're expecting an object and not an array of objects (An assumption from your render code), you'll need to extract it from the response as so `response.data.rows[0]`

Comment: What if I have more than 1 row? For example: array [ 0:object {name: "myname", id: 1}, 2: object { name: "myname2", id:2| ]. How can I get the second name dynamically ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Leo. In your case, you'd need to change the variables and how you're displaying them. So you'd set "row" as "rows" in your state to indicate plurality then do "this.setState({ rows: response.data.rows });" to set its value. Then you'd loop through the rows in the render function of the component.